# Prove or disprove - order types and constants

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

> Let $k$ and $l$ be natural numbers and let $\omega=[(\mathbb N, \le)], \ \eta=[(\mathbb Q, \le)]$ be order types (or ordinals).
>
> Prove or disprove the following:
>
> 1. if $k+\eta=l+\eta$ then $k=l$.
> 2. if $k+\omega=l+\omega$ then $k=l$.
> 3. $2014\cdot\omega=2014+\omega$

For 1, I'm not sure, the only way for $k+\eta=l+\eta$ to be true is if the two constants are equal, because if they weren't then it wouldn't be true. That's obviously not formal enough.

For 2, we know from ordinal arithmetic that $n\in\mathbb N+\omega=\omega$ so let's take two different natural numbers instead of $k$ and $l$ and we'll get that the first term is true but the second isn't. Is that enough to prove it ?

For 3, this is the way I see it: $\{2014,2\cdot 2014,...n\cdot2014\}=2014\cdot\omega\neq2014+\omega=\omega$, is it enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINTS:**

1. You can prove this by induction on $k$.
2. Yes, this is enough to disprove this. For concreteness, $k=0, l=1$.
3. Recall that $2014\cdot\omega=\sup\{2014\cdot n\mid n\in\omega\}$, and that $2014+\omega=\sup\{2014+n\mid n\in\omega\}$.

Comment: So 1 is true ? what is the base of induction ? About 3, why are they equal to these supermums ?

Comment: Well, for $k=0$ note that if $\eta=l+\eta$, then $l=0$, otherwise one of the orders has a least element and the other doesn't. As for the third, how do you define the addition and multiplication of two well-orders?

Comment: Our professor told us the it goes like this $\{what\}\cdot\{how \  much\}$ so for example: $\omega\cdot 2014=\{\omega\cdot\omega\cdot...\cdot\omega\}$ 2014 times.

Comment: Are you sure that you didn't misunderstand your professor?

Comment: That's exactly what she said about multiplication...

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, then.

Comment: I know she was pretty bad but that's irrelevant now. I just read through the wiki aritcal about ordinal arithmetic and there's no mention of supermum http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic

Comment: Yes, it does. The supremum of ordinals is their limit.

Comment: I also went through my notes, they never showed this in class, although it does makes sense. Is there another way to solve it ? Also, is it true for all ordinals not just omega ?

Comment: Well, you might also have heavily misunderstood (or been misexplained by your teacher). "What" and "How much" are informal ways to say that we replace each point in the right order with a copy of the left order (so $\omega\cdot 2$ is to replace each point in $2$ by a copy of $\omega$, so it's $\omega+\omega$). Then you can show that $2014\cdot\omega$ is isomorphic to $\omega$. And no, this (nor the third) is not true for every infinite ordinal.

Comment: (About 3.) So if both sides are equal to omega, how come the two supermums are entirely different ?

Comment: Uhh... what do you mean?

Comment: I mean that if the equation is true then: $$2014\cdot\omega=2014+\omega=\omega$$ but $$\sup\{2014\cdot n\mid n\in\omega\} \neq \sup\{2014+n\mid n\in\omega\}$$.

Comment: If that is true, then clearly all mathematics is false; or maybe... just maybe, you have miscalculated something.

Comment: What is not true ?  

$$ 2014\cdot\omega=2014+\omega=\omega$$ 

Is true right ? 

So how are the two supermums the same ? Take any $n$, espcially when it tends to infinity, the difference between two supermums will be totally different...

Comment: Then you are calculating the supremum incorrectly.

Comment: Oh I'm not dealing with natural numbers here... I saw the difference of an order of magnitude of 3 and immediately assumed they can't be the same. Well thanks for all the help.

Comment: You're most welcome.